# html/css: table/grid of input elements enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: html, css, math

I need a table/grid of 2x2 input elements, enclosed in parenthesis.

The objective is, in a page with a mathematics test, allow user to introduce the values of a matrix. The matrix must appear in the usual form of parenthesis enclosing it.

That is, starting from this code or anything equivalent:

```html
<html>
<body>

A + B =
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

two corrections must be done:

- mandatory: the 2x2 matrix/grid/table of input elements must be enclosed in big parenthesis
- nice to have: the characters "A+B=" should appear in the same line than the matrix, centered vertically.

Note: the page supports MathJax, thus, solutions using MathJax are also valid.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using the table that you already have. Note that I used inline styles merely for the demo. You can create a style class as needed

```html
<html>
<body>


<table>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
    A+B=
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="font-size:2em">(</td>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
        
      <td rowspan="2"><span style="font-size:2em">)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  $INPUT_PATTERN  name="a11" autofocus/></td>
  
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```